# Hide border of transparent JScrollPane In Java

Tags: java, swing, border, jscrollpane

I have implemented JScrollpane and I had set opaque false. Now the problem is I am not able to hide it's border.

Code:

```
JPanel chapterContainerPanel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane chapterScrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
chapterContainerPanel.setOpaque(false);
chapterScrollPane.setViewportView(chapterPanel);
JLabel blankLabelChapter = new JLabel();
blankLabelChapter.setOpaque(false);
blankLabelChapter.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 50));
blankLabelChapter.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);      
chapterContainerPanel.add(blankLabelChapter,BorderLayout.WEST);
chapterContainerPanel.add(chapterScrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
chapterScrollPane.setOpaque(false);
chapterScrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

Image:

[image]

I want to hide the border which is shown by arrow.

I have tried two ways:

```
Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
chapterScrollPane.setViewportBorder( border );
chapterScrollPane.setBorder(border);
chapterContainerPanel.setBorder(null);
```

and

```
chapterScrollPane.setBorder(null);
chapterScrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
```

but both are not working.

Comment: Have you tried setting an empty border?

Comment: ya i have tried empty border but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, and this worked for me:

```
chapterScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
chapterScrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Doing this that border will no longer appear, but the content of the panel inside the Scroll might go under the ScrollBar, so you need to adjust the border of the panel that is on the ViewPort, chapterContainerPanel in your case. You can also use an empty border to solve this, like that:

```
chapterContainerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this line of code, hope it will solve your issue,

```
chapterScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer
Use borderFactory to create empty border

```
chapterScrollPane.setBorder(createEmptyBorder());
```

Comment: What did you set it on? You have 3 major components there.

Comment: are you using pack() method ? If not try to add it. By the way you dont have to call setOpaque(false) method on every component as it is false by default

Comment: You also have a `chapterPanel` that you did not try to set an empty border to

Comment: chapterScrollPane.setViewportBorder(border) will set border to chapterPanel

Comment: @Dipali Vasani everything in your comments are quite empty words, different situations will be in that case that you posted an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE short, runnable, compilable